# Creating a table based on criteria from another table in r

Tags: r, conditional-statements, intervals, bin

I've a three column table (Table_1) and I would like to create another table based on Table_1. The table has personal ID and work start and end days.

```
Table_1 <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), Start_Day = c(1, 20, 38), End_Day = c(14, 29, 42))
```

The new table I would like to create will have two columns, namely ID and Week. The number of rows for each ID level is equal to the number of bins (weeks) of the End_Day and Start_Day. For example, ID A will have 2 week bins 1 (days 1-7) and 2 (days 8-14), ID B will have 3 week bins, 3 (days 15-21), 4 (days 22-28) and 5 (days 29-35).
The expected outcome is:

```
Table_2 <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C" ), Week = c(1, 2, ,3, 4, 5, 6))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to divide  `Start_Day` and `End_Day` by 7 and create a sequence between them using `map2` bringing the data in long format using `unnest`.

```
library(dplyr)

Table_1 %>%
  mutate_at(-1, ~ceiling(./7)) %>%
  mutate(Week = purrr::map2(Start_Day, End_Day, seq)) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(Week) %>%
  select(ID, Week)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
#   ID     Week
#  <fct> <int>
#1 A         1
#2 A         2
#3 B         3
#4 B         4
#5 B         5
#6 C         6
```